# What happens if a second HTTP request is made before I receive the response of the first request?

Tags: browser, webserver, tcp, web, packet

Suppose I made two requests from my web browser to a web server. I am sending the second request before I get the response of the first request. I know the response of the later request is rendered on my browser. But what happens to the first response? How does the browser know that which response is new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers use HTTP to communicate and the relevant standards defined how requests and responses are transported.

For HTTP/1 it might be that for the new request a new TCP connection is used in which case the response is expected in this connection too. Or it might be that an existing TCP connection is used to send the request in which the response is expected after the responses from all previous requests on this connection came in (they have a clearly defined size, so end of response is known).

For HTTP/2 this is more complicated since multiple requests interleave inside the TCP connection and so does multiple responses. But the framing defined in HTTP/2 defines clearly which request/response each of these message frames belongs too so that they can be reassembled at the end and the response can be assigned to the relevant request.